# Setting bits in a byte array using C#

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a byte array of 32 bytes where the first 4 bits of each byte (0 to 3) represent  the set or unset state of a number between 1 and 128. For example, If I am given the number 3, I need to set bit 2 in the first byte in the array. If I am given the number 9, I need to set bit 0 of the third byte in the array. The problem I have is finding a sensible way to do this in C#. I’m sure there must be a simple way to do it mathematically but so far haven’t been able to find a method. Whilst I scratch my head on this one I thought I’d see if anyone can give some advice.

--------- Update -------------------

Based on the answers given, I have produced the following function. This does exactly what I need. I may not have made it clear in my question what I needed but enough advice was given for me to find the right code.

```
// outputNumber = number passed into this function

byte[] bytes = new byte[32];

int bit = (outputNumber - 1) % 4;

byte byteSetting = (byte)(1 << bit);

bytes[(outputNumber - 1) / 4] |= byteSetting;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int byt = bitNumber / 4; // You could do byt = bitNumber >> 2
int bit = bitNumber % 4; // You could do bit = bitNumber & 3

bytes[byt] |= (byte)(1 << bit);
```

Where `bytes` is your byte array.

To reset it:

```
bytes[byt] &= (byte)(byte.MaxValue ^ (1 << bit));
```

To read the value of a byte:

```
var res = bytes[byt] & (byte)(1 << bit)
```

(if you are interested, `^` is the xor operator)

Comment: This answer helped me the most as it took into account my need to set bits in various bytes in an array rather than fixed bytes.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the bits in each byte in an array like this:

```
array[2] |= (byte)(1<<3); // set bit #4 / index 3 in array element #3 / index 2
```

You can clear a bit like this:

```
array[2] &= unchecked((byte)(~(1<<3))); // clear the same bit we set previously
```

Answer (score 1):

Needed something similar. On a 64 bit system use ulongs (32 bit -> uint) instead of bytes. The performace difference is quite significant.

```
public struct BitField {

    private ulong[] _Values;

    private BitField(ulong[] values) {
        _Values = values;
    }

    public static BitField New() {
        return new BitField(new ulong[] { 0ul, 0ul });
    }

    public BitField Clone() {
        return new BitField(new ulong[] { _Values[0], _Values[1] });
    }

    public void Clear() {
        _Values[0] = ulong.MinValue;
        _Values[1] = ulong.MinValue;
    }

    public void SetAll() {
        _Values[0] = ulong.MaxValue;
        _Values[1] = ulong.MaxValue;
    }

    public void AND_Combine(BitField bitField) {

        _Values[0] &= bitField._Values[0];
        _Values[1] &= bitField._Values[1];
    }

    public void OR_Combine(BitField bitField) {

        _Values[0] |= bitField._Values[0];
        _Values[1] |= bitField._Values[1];
    }

    public bool Intersects(BitField bitField) {

        if ((_Values[0] & bitField._Values[0]) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
        else {
            if ((_Values[1] & bitField._Values[1]) > 0) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;                                   
            }
        }
    }

    public bool this[int index] {
        get {
            if (index > 127 || index < 0) {
                return false;
            }
            int item = index >> 6;
            int bit = index % 64;

            ulong compare = 1ul << bit;
            return ((_Values[item] & compare) == compare);
        }
        set {
            if (index >= 0 || index < 128) {
                int item = index >> 6;
                int bit = index % 64;
                ulong compare = 1ul << bit;

                if (value) {
                    _Values[item] |= compare;
                }
                else {
                    _Values[item] &= ~compare;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```